# How I can integrate crossbar client (python3,asyncio) with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, integrate, crossbar

I run crossbar client with the runner of crossbar which run in the asyncio event loop. I want to call RPC by the trigger in tkinter. Is there any solution to combine them together?

Answer (score 0):

You can make an HTTP request to call your RPC. Everything described here [Crossbar HTTP Bridge Caller](https://crossbar.io/docs/HTTP-Bridge-Caller/).
Quick summary what you need to do:

1. Make configuration:

> The HTTP Caller is configured on a path of a Web transport - here is
>   part of a Crossbar configuration:
>
> ```
> {
>    "workers": [
>       {
>          "type": "router",
>          ...
>          "transports": [
>             {
>                "type": "web",
>                ...
>                "paths": {
>                   ...
>                   "call": {
>                      "type": "caller",
>                      "realm": "realm1",
>                      "role": "anonymous"
>                   }
>                }
>             }
>          ]
>       }
>    ]
> }
> ```

2. In your application make HTTP request

For example, using curl:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d '{"procedure": "com.example.add2", "args": [1, 2]}' \
    http://127.0.0.1:8080/call
```